# Scheduling should not accept 1 hour before a scheduled time

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I am making a scheduling system using VS2012 and SQLSERVER2012
I already validated that if the desired schedule day and time is already taken it will not submit.
This is the code

```
string sqlString = "Select [Date],[StartTime],[EndTime] FROM tbl_Schedule where [Date] ='" + txtDate.Value.ToShortDateString() + "' AND [StartTime] = '"+txtStart.Text+"' AND [EndTime] = '"+txtEnd.Text+"' ;";
```

[image]

How can I determine if my desired scheduled time is 1hr before the existing scheduled time.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string desiredTime = "10/10/2017 09:18";
        DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(desiredTime);

        string existingTime = "10/10/2017 10:18";
        DateTime e = DateTime.Parse(existingTime);

        if ((e-d).Hours <= 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("true");
        }
```

(Datetime e - DateTime d) will give you a TimeSpan object, then you just check the hours on that to see if it's less than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
string desiredTime = "10/10/2017 09:18";
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(desiredTime);

string existingTime = "10/10/2017 10:18";
DateTime e = DateTime.Parse(existingTime);

if (e.Hour - d.Hour == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("true");
}
```